# Force.com with PKB - Only 3 Articles are visible

Tags: visualforce, force.com, knowledge, articles

I set a force.com site and I discovered that only 3 published articles are visible on the front page, but when I use the search field I can see all articles.

What is the way to display all articles, even if I have to split them into pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the PBK Settings tab, select the site, then under common setup for popular article does it say 3? I'm pretty sure this where you can adjust the number on the home page.

[image]

The number of articles returned on a search is under the PKB Web setup tab:

[image]